# entry.get() with a tkinter toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program I am writing that has a root `Tk()` window as well as an admin `Toplevel()` that opens based on a condition. Inside the admin toplevel I have an `Entry()` however I cannot use `.get()` without getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is a sample code of my problem

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
root.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)

def proceed():
    admin = tkinter.Toplevel()
    admin.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
    admin.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)

    entry = Entry(admin).pack()
    entry.get()

button = Button(root, text="Proceed", command=proceed).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you assign `entry = Entry(admin).pack()` you are calling the `pack` method of the created widget which returns `None` so `entry` gets assigned `None`. Assign `entry = Entry(admin)` and then `pack` or `grid` the widget.

The same problem will occur when you try and assign `button`.

Comment: Thanks that helped.